# How to solve $\bigcap_{k=1}^{5}[\bigcup_{n=1}^{k}X_{n}]$ and $\bigcap_{k=5}^{\infty}[\bigcup_{n=3}^{k}X_{n}]$? When $X_{n}=\{n+1,n+2,...,2n\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Let $X_{n}=\{n+1,n+2,...,2n\}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N^{+}}$ What are

(i) $\bigcap_{k=1}^{5}[\bigcup_{n=1}^{k}X_{n}]$

I solve the inside through the loop outside $\bigcup_{n=1}^{k}X_{n}$

$
k=1 \\
n=1:\{2\} \\
\ \\ 
k=2 \\
n=1:\{2\}\\n=2:\{3,4\} \\
k=3 \\
n=1:\{2\}\\n=2:\{3,4\} \\ n=3:\{4,5,6\} \\
... \\k=5\\
n=k:\{2,3,...,k+1,k+2,...2k\}$

$\bigcap_{k=1}^{5}[k+1,k+2,...2k]=\{2\}$

Is this correct?

(ii)$\bigcap_{k=5}^{\infty}[\bigcup_{n=3}^{k}X_{n}]$

$
k=5 \\
n=3:\{4,5,6\} \\ n=4:\{5,6,7,8\} \\ n=5:\{6,7,8,9,10\}
\ \\ 
k=6 \\
n=3:\{4,5,6\} \\ n=4:\{5,6,7,8\} \\ n=5:\{6,7,8,9,10\} \\ n=6:\{7,8,9,10,11,12\} \\
... \\ k=\infty \\ n=k:
\{4,5,6,...k+1,k+2,....2k\}$

$\bigcap_{k=5}^{\infty}[\bigcup_{n=3}^{k}X_{n}]=\{4,5,6\}$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that

$$\begin{align*}&X_{n+1}=\{n+2,n+3\ldots,2n+2\}\\&\\ &a<b<c\quad\text{and}\quad \{a,c\}\subset X_n\implies b\in X_n,\quad a,b,c\in\Bbb N\end{align*}$$

Hence

$$X_n\cup X_{n+1}=\{n+1,\ldots,2n+2\}$$

Then by induction on $m$ we can show that

$$Y_{k,m}:=\bigcup_{n=k}^mX_n=\{k+1,\ldots,2m\}\tag{1}$$ what implies that $$Y_{1,m}=\{2,\ldots,2m\}$$ Then from $(1)$ we also can see that $$Y_{k,m}\subsetneq Y_{k,m+1}$$ Hence $$\bigcap_{m=1}^M Y_{1,m}=Y_{1,1}=\{2\},\qquad\bigcap_{m=5}^\infty Y_{3,m}=Y_{3,5}=\{4,\ldots,10\}$$

Comment: @ Masacroso Would you please elaborate the part "Then clearly we have that" $Y_{k,m}=\bigcup_{n=k}^{m}X_{n}=\{k+1,...,2m\} \implies Y_{1,m}=\{2,...,2m\}$? I don't see how this part comes from the previous $X_{n}\cup X_{n+1}=\{n+1,...,2n+2\}$

Comment: It is a consequence of $$X_n\cup X_{n+1}=\{n+1,\ldots,2n+2\}$$ You can see it by induction on $m$ in $\bigcup_{n=k}^m X_n$. The above represent the case for $m=k+1$. In the induction step we have that $$\bigcup_{n=k}^{m+1}X_n=X_{m+1}\cup\left(\bigcup_{n=k}^mX_n\right)=X_{m+1}\cup\{k+1,\ldots,2m\}=\{k+1,\ldots,2(m+1)\}$$

Comment: @ Masacroso $2(k+1)$ instead of $2(m+1)$, right? was it a typo?

Comment: @Tmm No, its not a typo. If it would be $2(k+1)$ instead of $2(m+1)$ then $$\{k+1,\ldots,2(k+1)\}=X_k\cup X_{k+1}$$ Im using different index than yours, what can be the source of confusion, sorry.

Comment: I didnt mention in my first comment that the induction hypothesis is $$\bigcup_{n=k}^m X_n=\{k+1,\ldots,2m\}$$

Comment: @ Masacroso would you please take a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2313060/how-to-prove-f-bigcap-alpha-in-au-alpha-subseteq-bigcap-alpha-in  and give comment or solution? I have done my proof but don't know if it is correct.